# Record instruction addresses of page faults with perf

Tags: linux, perf

I would like to get addresses of the instructions which leads to major page faults using `perf`.
I have a simple program:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd = open("path to large file several Gb", O_RDONLY);
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd, &st);
    void* ptr = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    const uint8_t* data = (const uint8_t*) ptr;

    srand(time(NULL));
    size_t i1 = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * st.st_size;
    size_t i2 = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * st.st_size;
    size_t i3 = ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * st.st_size;

    printf("%x[%lu], %x[%lu], %x[%lu]\n", data[i1], i1, data[i2], i2, data[i3], i3);

    munmap(ptr, st.st_size);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using `gcc -g -O0 main.c`
and run `perf record -e major-faults -g -d ./a.out`

Next I open the resulting report using `perf report -g`
The report says that there are 3 major page faults (it's correct),
but I can't understand addresses of the instructions which leads to the page faults.
The report is below:

```
# To display the perf.data header info, please use --header/--header-only options.
#
#
# Total Lost Samples: 0
#
# Samples: 3  of event 'major-faults'
# Event count (approx.): 3
#
# Children      Self  Command  Shared Object     Symbol                
# ........  ........  .......  ................  ......................
#
   100.00%     0.00%  a.out    libc-2.23.so      [.] __libc_start_main 
              |
              ---__libc_start_main
                 main

   100.00%   100.00%  a.out    a.out             [.] main              
              |
              ---0x33e258d4c544155
                 __libc_start_main
                 main

   100.00%     0.00%  a.out    [unknown]         [.] 0x033e258d4c544155
              |
              ---0x33e258d4c544155
                 __libc_start_main
                 main
```

`a.out` doesn't contain an address `0x33e258d4c544155` or something which ends with `155`.

The question is how to get instruction addresses which leads to page faults?

Comment: Welcome to SO - excellent first question! Thanks for including a thorough description for reproducing it.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I cannot reproduce your example, i.e. I'm not getting any samples with the `major-faults` event. But I can explain with a different example.

The `pref report` output is misleading, it doesn't the three events, it shows the three stack levels. It's much easier to understand by using `perf script` - which shows the actual events (including their stacks). The entries look like this (repeated for each sample):

```
a.out 22107 14721.378764:   10000000 cycles:u: 
            5653c1afb134 main+0x1b (/tmp/a.out)
            7f58bb1eeee3 __libc_start_main+0xf3 (/usr/lib/libc-2.29.so)
        49564100002cdb3d [unknown] ([unknown])
```

Now you see the function stack with the virtual instruction address, nearest symbol and offset from the symbol. If you want to fiddle with the addresses yourself, you can run `perf script --show-mmap-events`, which tells you:

```
a.out 22107 14721.372233: PERF_RECORD_MMAP2 22107/22107: [0x5653c1afb000(0x1000) @ 0x1000 00:2b 463469 624179165]: r-xp /tmp/a.out
                                                          ^ Base         ^ size    ^ offset                             ^ file
```

Then you can do the math for `0x5653c1afb134` by subtracting the base `0x5653c1afb000` and adding the offset `0x1000` - you get the address of the instruction or return address within the file.

You also see that `0x49564100002cdb3d` is not mapped, could not be resolved - it's just garbage from the frame-pointer based stack unwinding. You can ignore it. You can also use `--call-graph dwarf` or `--call-graph lbr` which seem to show more sensible stack origins.